# Fitting GLMMs for binomial data produces Error and Warning messages when using different fitting procedures in R.

Tags: r, glmm, lme4-nlme

I am trying to fit GLMM's to my data using the glmer function available in R's lme4 package. The data is available under the name block1and2 at: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=1B727FC7180E87DF%21119

I keep getting error or warning messages. Can anybody help me get rid of them.
There is probably a problem with the low number of Virus positive samples.Can these problems be resolved using GLMMs or should I think of other statistical tests?
N.B. this is a similar problem I had posted about concerning a similar data set and similar analyses ([After trying various optimzers, model simplification running more iterations, when fitting GLMMs, R still produces warning messages](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111553/after-trying-various-optimzers-model-simplification-running-more-iterations-wh))

Tried fitting the model:
`Line.glmer<-glmer(Virus_DNA~Line+(1|Block/Day_of_Analyses),family=binomial,data=data)`

Only to get the error message
`Error: (maxstephalfit) PIRLS step-halvings failed to reduce deviance in pwrssUpdate`

When running the code, with more iterations:
`Line.glmer<-glmer(Virus_DNA~Line+(1|Block/Day_of_Analyses),family=binomial,data=data,control=glmerControl(optCtrl=list(maxfun=1e9)))`

I get the same message.

When running the code with the optimizer bobyqa:
`Line.glmer<-glmer(Virus_DNA~Line+(1|Block/Day_of_Analyses),family=binomial,data=data,control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa",optCtrl=list(maxfun=1e9)))`

I get the warning messages: 
`Warning messages:
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00163126 (tol = 0.001, component 5)
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 2 negative eigenvalues`

When running the code with the optimizer Nelder_Mead:
'Line.Nelder_Mead.glmer<-glmer(Virus_DNA~Line+(1|Block/Day_of_Analyses),family=binomial,data=data,control=glmerControl(optimizer="Nelder_Mead",optCtrl=list(maxfun=1e9)))'

I get the error message:
`Error: (maxstephalfit) PIRLS step-halvings failed to reduce deviance in pwrssUpdate`

I have also tried the optimizer "nlminb" from the package "optimx". With the code
`Line.nlminb.glmer<-glmer(Virus_DNA~Line+(1|Block/Day_of_Analyses),family=binomial,data=data,                     control=glmerControl(optimizer="optimx",optCtrl=list(method="nlminb")))`

Getting the warning messages:
`Warning messages:
1: In optimx.check(par, optcfg$ufn, optcfg$ugr, optcfg$uhess, lower,  :
  Parameters or bounds appear to have different scalings.
  This can cause poor performance in optimization. 
  It is important for derivative free methods like BOBYQA, UOBYQA, NEWUOA.
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00184741 (tol = 0.001, component 5)
3: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 2 negative eigenvalues`

Similarly with the optimizer "nlminb" from the package "optimx":
`Line.LBFGSB.glmer<-glmer(Virus_DNA~Line+(1|Block/Day_of_Analyses),family=binomial,data=data,
control=glmerControl(optimizer="optimx",optCtrl=list(method="L-BFGS-B")))`

Produces the warning messages:
`Warning messages:
1: In optimx.check(par, optcfg$ufn, optcfg$ugr, optcfg$uhess, lower,  :
  Parameters or bounds appear to have different scalings.
  This can cause poor performance in optimization. 
  It is important for derivative free methods like BOBYQA, UOBYQA, NEWUOA.
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00330343 (tol = 0.001, component 5)
3: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model is nearly unidentifiable: large eigenvalue ratio
 - Rescale variables?`